# Creating a related case automatically upon account creation?

Tags: case, account

I'm trying to create a new case with a certain name (let's say "AccountName Awaits Info") and certain fields populated as soon as the account itself is created (the account should be the parent of said case). It seems simple enough but I'm not sure what settings or code I'd have to go through in order to do this.

How would I figure this out?

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend taking a look at process builder for this. The guide can be found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015300000035wMDAAY). A tutorial can be found [here](http://developerforce.github.io/lightning-process-builder-tutorial/). And a trailhead module can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/business_process_automation/process_builder?utm_campaign=trailhead&utm_source=website&utm_medium=lightning-wiki).

Comment: JennyB Just curious. Why not a trigger?!

Comment: @Seesh it's a relatively simple use case and I typically try to do clicks before code so in the future if an adjustment is needed it can be done by an admin via the UI.

Comment: You're right. I just remember that Process Builder has the "Create Records" feature. Thanks. I have only used Process Builder to supersede the existing workflow rules.